# Trying to create remember-me in django, found a snippet, not sure of implementation

Tags: python, django, session, authentication

So I've been researching making a remember me function in Django, for cookies that will last longer.

I found this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1881/

```
def login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('remember_me', None):
            request.session.set_expiry(0)
    return auth_views.login(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But I am not sure how to use it. Will this just overwrite the other login function? Do I have to explicitly point it here in the urls.py (probably, right?)? I am also using [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) will this make any problem with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A lot of these questions hinge on how you have login implemented right now. Are you using a view of your own or are you using django.contrib.auth.views.login or are you using something that python-social-auth provides?

Comment: I am using python-social-auth for logging in, user can just log in trough social networks.

Comment: I know I can do SESSION_COOKIE_AGE and set it as default, but I want it to be a choice.

Comment: Have you tried http://code.google.com/p/django-remember-me/ ?

Comment: I can't use it in this particular situation. Anyway, I decided to not do this at the end after carefully evaluating all, not a priority. Thanks.